# Bundle tracker and bundle install/start order

Tags: java, osgi

Let's suppose we have two osgi bundles - bundleA and bundleB. BundleA contains bundle tracker that must find bundleB. So, two possible install/start orders:

1. Install and start bundleA, install and start bundleB
2. Install and start bundleB, install and start bundleA

Does OSGi specs guarantee that in variant two bundle tracker will find bundleB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes depending upon how you configure the bundle states to be tracked by the BundleTracker. Assuming you are tracking active bundles, then it does not matter what order the bundles are installed or started.